# What is an adjective that describes the property of conferring fitness?

Tags: evolution, terminology

I find it wordy to repeat

> trait X is a trait that confers fitness.

I wonder if I can instead write

> trait X is useful.

If not, is there an adjective that describes this property of conferring fitness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Terms**

A trait variant that is associated to a higher fitness than another variant is said to be **beneficial** or sometimes **adaptive**. On the other hand, a trait variant that is associated to a lower fitness is said to be **deleterious** or sometimes **maladaptive**.

**"beneficial / deleterious" vs "adaptive / maladaptive"**

The terms are very similar but I would tend to think that there are tendencies of using either "beneficial / deleterious" or "adaptive / maladaptive" depending upon the specific context.

These terms can also be used when talking about genetic variants and not only phenotypic trait variants. In evolutionary genetics, the terms "beneficial / deleterious" are used more often than "adaptive / maladaptive".

Also, in general, the terms "adaptive / maladaptive" are often used in absence of variation for the trait in question in the population while the terms "beneficial / deleterious" are most often used when there is variation in the population.

**Note**

Note that `trait X is a trait that confers fitness` does not make much sense as is explained [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/68168/does-evolution-only-give-rise-to-traits-that-confer-fitness/68172#68172).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure "conferring fitness" is the correct way of thinking about things, since fitness is typically a complex combination of traits, but I think the adjective you are looking for is "adaptive" - though this adjective implies that it has been selected as well as that it has contributed positively to fitness, for any inheritable trait that has been around through a reproductive cycle both would necessarily be true.

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adaptive one of the example sentences is:

> Webbed feet is an adaptive trait in aquatic animals.